# Use the robot_name of launch file to MyRobotDriver

Tags: ros2, webots

I am following the tutorial [Setting up a robot simulation (Webots) ROS2 Humble](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Webots/Setting-Up-Simulation-Webots-Basic.html).

Here is my_robot.urdf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="My robot">
    <webots>
        <plugin type="my_package.my_robot_driver.MyRobotDriver" />
    </webots>
</robot>
```

Here is the part of robot_launch.py file:

```
my_robot_driver = WebotsController(
    robot_name='my_robot',
    parameters=[
        {'robot_description': robot_description_path},
    ]
)
```

Here is the part of my_robot_driver.py file:

```
class MyRobotDriver:
    def init(self, webots_node, properties):
        self.__robot = webots_node.robot

        self.__left_motor = self.__robot.getDevice('left wheel motor')
        self.__right_motor = self.__robot.getDevice('right wheel motor')

        self.__left_motor.setPosition(float('inf'))
        self.__left_motor.setVelocity(0)

        self.__right_motor.setPosition(float('inf'))
        self.__right_motor.setVelocity(0)

        self.__target_twist = Twist()

        rclpy.init(args=None)
        self.__node = rclpy.create_node('my_robot_driver')
        self.__node.create_subscription(Twist, 'cmd_vel', self.__cmd_vel_callback, 1)

    def __cmd_vel_callback(self, twist):
        self.__target_twist = twist
```

I want to take the robot_name from robot_launch.py file and use it inside the MyRobotDriver class of my_robot_driver.py file.

Following is the little part of my desired MyRobotDriver class code:

```
self.__target_twist = Twist()
name = robot_name   # here robot_name comes from launch file

rclpy.init(args=None)
self.__node = rclpy.create_node('my_robot_driver')
self.__node.create_subscription(Twist, f'{name}/cmd_vel', self.__cmd_vel_callback, 1)
```

Is there any way to implement `name = robot_name   # here robot_name comes from launch file` this line correctly? Here my_robot.urdf, robot_launch.py, my_robot_driver.py are from the tutorial.